# Able to store cards data in local storage and display them, but unable to remove them when i click on them

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

This is my fav icon component code, stores the data but unable to remove it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CiBeerMugFull } from "react-icons/ci";

function Faves({
  id,
  title,
  date,
  address,
  link,
  image,
  description,
  event_location_map,
  setSavedCards,
  cards = [],
}) {
  const [isFave, setIsFave] = useState(false);

  const handleFaveClick = () => {
    setIsFave(!isFave);
    if (!isFave) {
      const card = { id, title, date, event_location_map, address, link, image, description };
      onAdd(card);
    } else {
      handleRemoveFaveCard(id);
    }
  };

  const onAdd = (card) => {
    const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");
    const newFaveCards = [...faveCards, card];
    localStorage.setItem("faves", JSON.stringify(newFaveCards));
  };

  const handleRemoveFaveCard = (id) => {
    const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");
    const newFaveCards = faveCards.filter((card) => card.id !== id);
    setSavedCards(newFaveCards);
    localStorage.setItem("faves", JSON.stringify(newFaveCards));
  };


  return (
    <>
      {isFave || cards.some((card) => card.id === id) ? (
        <button onClick={handleFaveClick} style={{ border: "none" }}>
          <CiBeerMugFull className="text-yellow-600 h-10 w-10" />
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleFaveClick} style={{ border: "none" }}>
          <CiBeerMugFull className="text-black lg:text-black border-cyan-950 h-10 w-10" />
        </button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my save cards code...i get the setSavedCards is not a function..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "../cards/Card";
import Faves from "../faves/faves";

function SavedCards() {
  const [savedCards, setSavedCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");
    setSavedCards(faveCards);
  }, []);

  const handleFaveClick = (card) => {
    const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");

    const index = faveCards.findIndex((c) => c.id === card.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      const newFaveCards = [...faveCards, card];
      localStorage.setItem("faves", JSON.stringify(newFaveCards));
      setSavedCards(newFaveCards);
    } else {
      const newFaveCards = [
        ...faveCards.slice(0, index),
        ...faveCards.slice(index + 1),
      ];
      localStorage.setItem("faves", JSON.stringify(newFaveCards));
      setSavedCards(newFaveCards);
    }
  };

  const handleRemoveFaveCard = (id) => {
    const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");
    const newFaveCards = faveCards.filter((card) => card.id !== id);
    setSavedCards(newFaveCards);
    localStorage.setItem("faves", JSON.stringify(newFaveCards));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
      const faveCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faves") || "[]");
      setSavedCards(faveCards);
    });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", () => {});
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto mt-10" id="faves">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center mb-10">Saved Events</h1>
      {savedCards.length === 0 && (
        <p className="text-center text-lg">No saved events yet.</p>
      )}
      {savedCards.map((card) => (
        <div key={card.id}>
          <Card {...card} setSavedCards={setSavedCards}>
            <Faves
              {...card}
              setSavedCards={setSavedCards}
              handleFaveClick={handleFaveClick}
              handleRemoveFaveCard={handleRemoveFaveCard}
            />
          </Card>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SavedCards;
```

I have tried adding a remove button but it kills the overall UI, and the main problem is, it doesnt remeber the state, inside the saved events the beer icon is again in false state

Comment: Hi, I think there are some mistakes, which is fine tough. when defining an arrow function with variables (let, const, var), we can use them only after assigning them (not before). we can whether use function declaration (which will hoist) or just define variables in correct order. right now, when handleFaveClick (in Faves) invokes, onAdd and  handleRemoveFaveCard  are undefined.

Comment: hey, I finally solved it! Solution: In the "Faves" component, remove the setSavedCards function entirely, and in "SavedComponents" "handleFaveClick" function & handleRemoveFaveCard have been removed, now it works as expected, as we click the beer icon, the liked state is saved, with that in saved cards if I click it again, it gets removed, ...so for all this to work refresh is required that's kind of thing to be looked into now!